# Excel VBA IE NAVIGATE method does not return full HTML Page

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to extract first name of the actor from the url i am passing,
for my URL,i need to extact "Will Smith" from the HTML page.
[Web Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAO3f.png)

I know how to extract elements from HTML page using tag,classnaem etc.

But the problem i am facing is when i pass the URL, "https://ssl.ofdb.de/film/138627,I-Am-Legend"
in the response text,i am not at receiving the full HTML page,due to this i am not able extract the content "Will Smith".

I tried other methods like MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 also both returns the partial HTML page only

I have attached my code here,any one please help

```html
Sub Fetch_Info()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


ie.Visible = True
ie.Top = 0
ie.Left = 700
ie.Width = 1000
ie.Height = 750
ie.AddressBar = 0
ie.StatusBar = 0
ie.Toolbar = 0
ie.navigate "https://ssl.ofdb.de/film/138627,I-Am-Legend"

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04")

Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set doc = ie.document
doc.Focus


Debug.Print doc.DocumentElement.innerHTML

End Sub
```

Comment: What is it you wanna scrape from that webpage?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following css selector. `querySelector` returns the first node matched for the css pattern. The pattern is `[itemprop='actor'] span` which looks for a child `span` with parent element having attribute `itemprop` with value `actor`. Note, I am working off `ie.document` node.

```
Debug.Print ie.document.querySelector("[itemprop=actor] span").innerText
```

That content is static so you could use xhr and avoid overhead of browser. The response header charset is none so you need the response body.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetActor()
    Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    'required VBE (Alt+F11) > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library ;  Microsoft XML, v6 (your version may vary)

    Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://ssl.ofdb.de/film/138627,I-Am-Legend", False
        .send
         html.body.innerHTML = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = html.querySelector("[itemprop=actor] span").innerText
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a Ton,that really worked,also what modification do i need incase if i want the second actor name from that page? (Alice Braga).

Also when i debug print the entire HTML page,why i am not able to find the name "Will Smith"